# Error when installing PHP with brew

Tags: php, macos, homebrew

I am trying to install PHP with homebrew using [this tutorial](http://blog.stevenlu.com/2012/10/12/moving-away-from-mamp-and-into-homebrew/).
It is not successful.

```
 dewis-mbp-2:Desktop dewijones$ brew -v install php53 --with-mysql --with-imap --with-pgsql --with-suhosin
        Homebrew 0.9.5
        ==> Downloading http://www.php.net/get/php-5.3.28.tar.bz2/from/this/mirror
        Already downloaded: /Library/Caches/Homebrew/php53-5.3.28
        ==> Verifying php53-5.3.28 checksum
        tar xf /Library/Caches/Homebrew/php53-5.3.28
        ==> Patching
        patching file configure
        patching file configure.in
        patching file Zend/zend_language_parser.y
        patching file configure
        patching file Zend/acinclude.m4
        ==> rm Zend/zend_{language,ini}_parser.[ch]
        Error: No such file or directory - pg_config
```

Answer (score 2):

If you don't need PostgreSQL remove the --with-pgsql option. If you need PostgreSQL install it first with:

```
 brew install postgresql
```

Answer (score 0):

The following commands worked for me:

```
$ cd /usr/bin
$ ln -s /Library/PostgreSQL/9.3/bin/pg_config pg_config
$ brew -v install php53 --with-mysql --with-imap --with-pgsql --with-suhosin
```

Comment: Try to install postgress with brew too.

Answer (score 0):

1/ If you haven't installed Postgress already you could install it using [Postgress.app](http://postgresapp.com). You could also install it with homebrew using `brew install postgres92`. I'm going to assume you're using Postgress.app.

2/ When installing PHP through homebrew you'll need to point it to the correct directory with the Postgres binaries. When using Postgress.app that would be:

`brew -v install php53 --with-mysql --with-imap --with-pgsql=/Applications/Postgres.app/Contents/Versions/9.3/bin --with-suhosin`

If you installed postgres through homebrew you should replace `/Applications/Postgres.app/Contents/Versions/9.3/bin` with something like `/usr/local/Cellar/posgtgress/9.2/bin` (I think - I haven't used postgress via homebrew myself)